# If $W$ admits an injection of $k$-algebras in its coordinate ring, then $W$ is an unirational variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, affine-geometry

I'm studying algebraic geometry from *"Introduction to algebraic geometry"* by Hassett, and I did not understand a step in his proof of the following result (page 52):

> "If $W$ is an affine variety admitting an injection of $k$-algebras $\psi : k[W] → = k(x_1, \cdots , x_n)$ then $W$ is unirational."

The proof presented is:

> "Suppose we have an injection $\psi$ as above. By previous results, such a function yields a rational map $\rho : \mathbb{A}^n(k)  →  W$. If $\overline{\rho(U)} \neq W$ (where $U$ is the open set where $\rho$ is defined) then there must exist some $f \neq 0 \in k[W]$ vanishing on $\rho(U)$, contradicting the assumption that $\psi$ is injective."

My question is in the passage "there must exist some $f \neq 0 \in k[W]$ vanishing on $\rho(U)$, contradicting the assumption that $\psi$ is injective.". **Why must such a $f$ exist?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W$ is affine which means that its closed subsets are in one-to-one correspondence with radical ideals of $k[W]$ (this being the correspondence coming from the Nullstellensatz). Since $W$ is a variety, $k[W]$ has no nilpotent elements, so $(0)$ is radical, and corresponds to the entire closed set $W$ itself. Hence if $\overline{\rho(U)} \not= W$ then, since it is closed, there must be a corresponding radical ideal of $\overline{\rho(U)}$ in $k[W]$ which is not the zero ideal. $f$ is a non-zero element of this ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation $\overline{\rho(U)}$ is a proper closed subset of $W$, so the corresponding ideal in $k[W]$ is not just $\{0\}$.